# Show that [0,1] is closed using the definition.

Tags: real-analysis

So basically we need to prove that for every $x$ doesn't belong to $[0,1]$, there exist a $\delta > 0$ such that $(x-\delta, x+\delta) \cap [0,1]$ is empty set. I am not sure what to do, any hints?

Comment: Consider first $x > 1$. What might be a valid choice for $\delta$?

Comment: A valid choice for delta would be x-1

Answer (score 2):

You need to take delta so that delta < x-1 for x positive or delta < |x| for x negative.